# Using Windows Push Notification Services outside Metro

Tags: push-notification, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can non-Metro apps make use of the Windows Push Notification infrastructure? i.e. C# Desktop apps running on Windows 8? Or Windows 7 for that matter? It seems to be a pretty generic model, but the overviews I've read don't cover this.

A related question is - can Metro apps be written that use "live tiles" in a standalone app that is not part of the Windows 8 start screen? i.e. you create a container app which holds live tile-like entities but has nothing to do with the start screen.

Comment: There is a HubTile container in the Silverlight toolkit that allows for tile like look and feel other than on the start screen - you should be able to adapt some of that?

Answer (score 0):

(1) No, it cannot. Only the Metro style apps can use the Windows Push Notification Service.
(2) From looking at a lot of the apps, they have a lot of modern elements that look like tiles. It looks like every Metro app has a tile though, so I don't think there's a way to write a Metro app that can't be put there.